# Remove characters from query string

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string, redirect

I need to redirect

```
http://example.com/page/?Id=1253-23098-
```

to

```
http://example.com/page/1253-23098
```

This redirection also includes removal of '-' from end of query string.

What i've done is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Id=([0-9\-\0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/page/%1? [L,R=301]
```

which is redirecting me to

```
http://example.com/page/1253-23098-
```

I need to removed anything after "1253-23098" from my query string.

I've googling it from last 3-4 hours buts nothing seems to work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Id=(\d+-\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page/%1? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Id=([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/page/%1-%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct just that its not handling query string after 1253-23098" except '-', thanks for your effort